# Windows IoT installed in raspberry pi disconnects from wifi and stops running

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I have installed windows IoT 10 on raspberry pi 3 device. I connect the device to WiFi and have installed application and set it as default application. The problem is after some time application stops running (I have some GPIO pin connected to external sensors). If i connect the pi to ethernet without restarting the pi  can see the device in dashboard and can restart the application.

Not sure how to deal with this issue.

Comment: What's kind of the application, headed or headless? How long the application runs before it stops? How do you find the raspberry pi disconnect from wifi? Disconnection happens when the application stops?

Comment: Dint get your point, headed or headless?. Stops in 10 minutes aprrox (not consitant). . . Yup disconnection happenes when application stop

Comment: Using pin 18 and 26. And gnd

Comment: Headed application has UI and headless has not UI. Headless app is a background app. More information about application types supported on windows iot core you can reference [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/buildingappsforiotcore).

Comment: Do you mind showing your code?

Comment: It is headed. But i dont have any specific need for it. Will try running it in background.

Comment: Got the answer. The problem got solved once i changed os to insider version